# How to create wave forms in ModelSim Altera Starter

Tags: modelsim, intel-fpga

I'm using Altera ModelSim 10.1d for a verilog project for a class.  I can't figure out how to run the simulation properly.  I have a very simple verilog file (just a 2 to 1 multiplexer) and I want to try 4 different combinations of inputs.

According to the guides on Altera's site I've done the following:
1)  Clicked Simulate->Start Simulation and selected the mux file
2)  Clicked Add Wave in the 'Sim' pane
3)  Then clicked run.

All I get are some flat lines.  How can I modify the wave form of the inputs?  Right clicking an input in the objects pane and going to 'modify' has a 'change value' option but it is grayed out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a testbench that drives the inputs to the mux. The simulator doesn't know how to do that without being told. You can manually fiddle with the inputs in the wave window by right clicking on them and selecting the force dialog to set a new value but it is tedious to use for anything but debug.

Comment: Yea I know that now... this is one of the few times Office Hours beat StackOverflow for a small technical problem!